# How to pipe scp/ssh file transfer(pull) through tar (remote->local transfer initiated from local machine)

Tags: ssh, pipe, tar, scp

I would like to pipe an scp pull operation(sample without tar below) through tar, so that only one tar file is written for about 10 directories:

```
user@localhost:/home/user> scp -r remoteuser@remotehost:dir_to_transfer ./
```

I have directories on a remote machine that have about 10,000 small(~28k)files per directory to transfer. Due to file quotas, I don't have much free space to run the tar command on the remote host(remotehost). Due to firewall rules, I can only initiate the transfer from my local machine(localhost).

The sheer number of files makes the transfer very long.

I have found examples of how to do this when "pushing" the data, but would like to know how to do this when "pulling" the data.

Local machine info:

- OS:OpenSuSe 13.2(x86_64)
- bash 4.2.53(1)
- OpenSSH_6.6.1p1, OpenSSL 1.0.1k-fips 8 Jan 2015

Remote machine info:

- OS: CentOS release 5.11 (Final)
- bash 3.2.25(1)
- OpenSSH_4.3p2, OpenSSL 0.9.8e-fips-rhel5 01 Jul 2008

Answer (score 6):

try from `user@localhost`

```
 > ssh -l remoteuser remotehost "tar cf - dir_to_transfert" > remote.tar
```

where

- `>` is the prompt
- `ssh -l remoteuser remotehost` connect you to remote host
- `"tar cf - dir_to_transfert"` perform remote tarin to standard output
- `> remote.tar` redirect ssh's output to localfile name remote.tar

this will work if you are allowed tar on remote host.

Comment: You have an extraneous `)` character

Comment: @Barmar thank, my first intend was `( ssh ... ) > foo` , but since local shell get `>` first.

Comment: Yeah,I had a feeling it was an edit like that